# Jquery, to get the font family and change color

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the font-family of an `h1` tag and change the color of `h2` to `#CCC`, but so far it doesn't work. I think I did it in a wrong way. I'm new with jQuery coding, so really appreciate the help.

Here is my jquery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.h1').click(function(){ 
        $(this).css('h2', '#CCC');
    }); 
});
```

Please help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $(function() {  
$('.h1').click(function(){
    $(this).css('h2', '#CCC');

  });
});

Comment: I dont know how to add it there, it always giving me error so i just psted in the comment

Comment: Please can you copy the markup that has those 2 tags and paste in the summary of your question?

Comment: There is no attempt at doing anything with font family in the code posted. There was no HTML code posted, so we cannot know what is wrong with it. The jQuery code does not refer to anything as `h1` element, only an element in class `h1`, which is something completely different. And `h2` is not a CSS property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the way if h1 and h2 are class names then use `dot` prefixed else just give them as is. I assume they are class name in your markup.

```
$(function() {
 $('.h1').click(function(){ 
    $('.h2').css('color', '#CCC');
   alert($(this).css('font-family')); //this will give you font-family
 }); 
});
```

Comment: I assume h1 and h2 aren't class names and he wrote the dot since he's new to jQuery!

Answer (score 2):

to set the color

```
$(function() {
  $('h1').click(function(){ 
     $('h2').css('color', '#CCC');
     alert($('h2').css('font-family')); //this will give you font-family
  }); 
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/38Fzv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You have made it in wrong way 
:

```
$(function() {
 $('.h1').click(function(){ 
$('.h2').css('color', '#CCC');
 }); 
});
```

try this code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on markup like the following:

```
<h1 class="h1">I'm an H1</h1>
<h2 class="h2">I'm an H2</h2>
```

This should be your code

```
$(function() {
    $('.h1').click(function(){ 
        var fontFamily = $(this).css("font-family"); // only accessible in this scope
        $('.h2').css('background-color', '#CCC');
    }); 
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/FFkDJ/)

**Note:** If you are using 'h1' as class names for `h1` tags, I recommend you reconsider. That's highly unspecific and could become confusing.